# Error bulk loading XML file in SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm updating a SSIS task and getting a weird error: When executed, it says it can't bulk load a file the same SSIS task created.

This task retrieves a .zip file, extracts it in a path and then runs a stored procedure to bulk load the XML file, insert it's contents in some tables etc.

It's printing the following error in the logs:

```
Empresas:Error: Executing the query "execute carga.sp_cargaInicialEmpresas ?, ?" 
failed with the following error: "Erro na procedure xxxxx2016_CI.carga.sp_cargaInicialEmpresas)
Linha: 1Mensagem: Cannot bulk load because the file "C:\xxxxx2016\arquivos\Empresa\2017\2403\02\151423_ExecucaoEmpresas\ExecucaoEmpresas.xml" could not be opened. 
Operating system error code 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).". 
Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
```

This is a local path, not a network path, and the .xml file is created by the SSIS task itself. I checked the path in windows explorer and the file is there, waiting to be read.

Also the **SQLSERVERAGENT** user has all permissions in the "C:\xxxxx2016\arquivos\Empresa\2017\2403\02\151423_ExecucaoEmpresas\" directory.

How can I solve this?

Comment: SQLSERVER doesn't have access to the folder.

Comment: Hi @KashifQureshi , Thanks for commenting! But how can it not have access to the folder if the .xml file is extracted by the same task?
I checked the folder properties and the SQLSERVERAGENT has full control and other permissions. =(

Comment: Do you have DelayValidation set to true on the "execute carga..." task?   What happens if you manually execute that procedure in SSMS?

Comment: @TabAlleman it's set to false. I'll change it's value and try again, thanks.

Comment: @TabAlleman unfortunatelly the error persists when changing this flag.

Comment: Does the user you are executing with have bulk operation permissions? try doing bulk import using ssms manually by that user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a very misleading error message. 
After a few days trying to work it out, I found out that the database was misconfigured in my SSIS task connections.

Answer (score 1):

This is an OS issue -- Error 3.  The path does not exist.  Please see system error codes [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx).  Please check on the full path to the file.

An access issue would an error code 5.

Also, it depends on who is executing the SSIS package.  Are you doing it from the server using your login?  Are you running the package from SQL Agent under that credential?  Did you change the run as credential in the job.

Like someone said, try executing it by hand.  If it fails, then it is the Stored Procedure code.  If it passes, then it is the path passed from SSIS to the SP.  Make sure you know what your working directory is.

Tell me how you make out.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping me!
I have access to the folder and the file is right there. =( I'll past it's path from my windows explorer: \\xxx-v034\c$\xxxxx2016\arquivos\Empresa\2017\2403\02\151423_ExecucaoEmpresas
I'm obligated to hide some names from this path to avoid identifying the company I work for. 

This task runs every 10 minutes in this server, I don't test it manually. The standard execution report says the Caller is NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT. I presume it's the user that runs the task. 

I'll try executing it manually.

Comment: Executed it manually, got the same error message. 
I was hoping there was something wrong with the slashes, some trivial mistake in the path...
But it seems to be fine. The update that apparently broke this SSIS task involved not using an SSIS parameter for the file path, but retrieving this path from a DB table.

Comment: It seems like you are changing paths.  The first one was a c: drive, the second one is a network path.  Make a copy of the file and stored procedure.  Save it in a know location such as the log directory of sql files.  Try it again.  Something broke ...

Comment: Hi! Thanks again and sorry for taking so long to answer. I'm executing this package in a remote server, that's the reason for printing **\\xxx-034** in that comment. But the DB is in the same place as the file (I swear lol). 
I tried pasting this same path inside the stored procedure and manually running it, and it found the file and opened it correctly. =(

Comment: If I am getting this correctly, you are executing a stored procedure from SSIS.  It runs correctly from your machine but does not run corrrectly from the server.  Add some logging to the process.  Create a log table in the database that has the stored procedure.  Save the two parameters.  I assume one is the file name.  Save the SUSER_NAME() to the same log table.  This will tell you who is trying to execute the SP.  It is definitely a file path issue as the error message says.  There is also the 32 bit vs 64 bit mode of SSIS.  But I do not think that is coming to play.

Comment: Hi @CRAFTY! I'm sorry for taking so long to answer. I tried to log what is happening in the stored procedure, but with no luck. I first suspected my logs weren't going to the log table because they were inside a BEGIN TRY block. But now I'm trying to insert them before the begin try and the stored procedure keeps crashing without inserting anything in my dbo.LOG table. =(
I'm try to solve this and will comment here as ASAP.

Comment: I just re-read your process.  Here are some things to test:  1 - Are you sure the zip file is fully extracted before you start to try and read the file.  2 - Make sure you are doing this in a test environment.  3 - Rewrite the stored procedure and manually test it.  This should have that logging.  4 - Are you using the SSIS DB (catalog)?  This might have more detailed information.  Good Luck ...

Comment: Problem solved! 
I had 2 connections in my connection manager. All the DB-related tasks before this one connected to db-1, and this task was the first of the package to connect to db-2. Sadly I misconfigured my db-2, trying to connect it to a different network server. 
Unfortunately the error message was very misleading. =]